# Unable to Run React Native Project after installing react-native-elements on M1 mac

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, apple-m1

I have created a new project and it was running fine until I installed react-native-elements and I have gone through each step but still it throws error and after searching for solution I found out that it has something to do with M1 but not able to solve it .
This is the error thrown by the system :

```
debug Command line invocation:
    
debug /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace ReactNativeStarterKit.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme ReactNativeStarterKit -destination id=7E5DA355-488F-44C4-808B-68640668197A

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES


debug Prepare build

debug error: The Legacy Build System will be removed in a future release. You can configure the selected build system and this deprecation message in File > Workspace Settings.

debug Build Preparation

debug The Legacy Build System will be removed in a future release. You can configure the selected build system and this deprecation message in File > Workspace Settings.


error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening ReactNativeStarterKit.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace ReactNativeStarterKit.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme ReactNativeStarterKit -destination id=7E5DA355-488F-44C4-808B-68640668197A

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare build
error: The Legacy Build System will be removed in a future release. You can configure the selected build system and this deprecation message in File > Workspace Settings.
Build Preparation
The Legacy Build System will be removed in a future release. You can configure the selected build system and this deprecation message in File > Workspace Settings.


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Prepare build
(1 failure)
```

Comment: Well, a lot of packages for m1 need to be installed with arch -x86_64 modifier. For example ```arch -x86_64 pod install```. So try removing Pods folder and Podfile.lock, and then running ```arch -x86_64 pod install```, for me it usually helps.

Comment: I'm not sure that your problem is related to M1 though.

Comment: Nothing happened, still getting the same result